# Is it possible to use android.graphics.Camera on ViewGroup?

Tags: android, 3d, transform

**My purpose:** I have a RelativeLayout acting like a button (clickable) and it has multiple views inside of it: TextView, Image. I want to transform this RelativeLayout alltogether (as if it is like a single object) in 3D coordinates.

**What I know:** I know that by using Camera and modifiying Matrix, i can really transform an Image view in 3d.
However, i can't do this on a ViewGroup like a RelativeLayout as i can't modify it's matrix.

**Question:** Is it possible and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well android isn't built to work that way, each view in android is responsible for drawing it self, so you can't just put a certain render logic in a parent view and expect the child views  to cope with it.

Easiest thing I can think of is to create your own big view and draw your child views manually inside it, then I believe you can achieve the desired effect by using the camera object with your canvas.

Or you can go openGL but that would only make sense if you have performance issue in the above approach

Comment: Would you please show me the way to drawing views manually? I will need an Image as the background + overlaying a text with semi transparent background at the bottom.

Comment: take a look here http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html